# Check for words in a sentence

Tags: python, utf-8

I write a program in Python. The user enters a text message. It is necessary to check whether there is a sequence of words in this message. Sample. Message: "Hello world, my friend.". Check the sequence of these two words: "Hello", "world". The Result Is "True". But when checking the sequence of these words in the message: "Hello, beautiful world "the result is"false".  When you need to check the presence of only two words it is possible as I did it in the code, but when combinations of 5 or more words is difficult. Is there any small solution to this problem?

```
s=message.text
s=s.lower()
lst = s.split()
elif "hello" in lst and "world" in lst :
    if "hello" in lst:
        c=lst.index("hello")
    if lst[c+1]=="world" or lst[c-1]=="world":
        E=True
    else:
        E=False
```

Comment: If you split `"hello, beautiful world"` into a list the list will contain `"hello,"`, not `"hello"`.

Comment: Do you also want "world hello" to return true? If there are 5 words, can they be in any order?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, but if the message will be: " World how are you? Hello everyone." My program is quite working for such a case, but if you need to find consistently standing, but in any order 5 words?...

Comment: Strip out the punctuation before you split, and you probably want to turn everything into a single case (e.g. `lower()`).

Comment: @Alex Yes they can be in any order, but consistently i.e. between them there is no other words.  "hello", "my", "dear","friend", "Dima" or "my", "dear","friend","Dima", "hello" or other variations.

Comment: What's the longest possible sequence of words to search for and does this need to be faster than, say, a second? Need to know if a brute force approach is acceptable for handling all possible orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will clarify your requirement first:

- ignore case
- consecutive sequence
- match in any order, like permutation or anagram
- support duplicated words

if the number is not too large, you can try this easy-understanding but not the fastest way.

1. split all words in text message
2. join them with `' '`
3. list all the permutation of words and join them with `' '` too, For
   example, if you want to check sequence of `['Hello', 'beautiful', 'world']`. The permutation will be `'Hello beautiful world'`,
   `'Hello world beautiful'`, `'beautiful Hello world'`... and so on.
4. and you can just find whether there is one permutation such as
   `'hello beautiful world'` is in it.

The sample code is here:

```
import itertools
import re

# permutations brute-force, O(nk!)
def checkWords(text, word_list):
    # split all words without space and punctuation
    text_words= re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower())

    # list all the permutations of word_list, and match
    for words in itertools.permutations(word_list):
        if ' '.join(words).lower() in ' '.join(text_words):
            return True
    return False

    # or use any, just one line
    # return any(' '.join(words).lower() in ' '.join(text_words) for words in list(itertools.permutations(word_list)))
def test():
    # True
    print(checkWords('Hello world, my friend.', ['Hello', 'world', 'my']))
    # False
    print(checkWords('Hello, beautiful world', ['Hello', 'world']))
    # True
    print(checkWords('Hello, beautiful world Hello World', ['Hello', 'world', 'beautiful']))
    # True
    print(checkWords('Hello, beautiful world Hello World', ['Hello', 'world', 'world']))
```

But it costs a lot when words number is large, k words will generate k! permutation, the time complexity is O(nk!).

I think a more efficient solution is `sliding window`. The time complexity will decrease to O(n):

```
import itertools
import re
import collections

# sliding window, O(n)
def checkWords(text, word_list):
    # split all words without space and punctuation
    text_words = re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower())
    counter = collections.Counter(map(str.lower, word_list))
    start, end, count, all_indexes = 0, 0, len(word_list), []

    while end < len(text_words):
        counter[text_words[end]] -= 1
        if counter[text_words[end]] >= 0:
            count -= 1
        end += 1

        # if you want all the index of match, you can change here
        if count == 0:
            # all_indexes.append(start)
            return True

        if end - start == len(word_list):
            counter[text_words[start]] += 1
            if counter[text_words[start]] > 0:
                count += 1
            start += 1

    # return all_indexes
    return False
```

Comment: This is a good start. It should be pointed out exactly which characters a searched word is allowed to contain with this code. It also needs to be generalised to find the search words in any order (but still together).

Comment: Okay, but I also need the "world hello" answer to be True. And if words 3 the any a combination of of these words. Should I use "permutations" for this ?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand at first time, you can see whether the new version is what you need @The person with the question

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need.

Comment: You are welcome, and it costs a lot when words count increase, it will generate K! permutation. I will update a more efficient way maybe later. @The person with the question

Comment: I have update a more efficient solution `sliding window`, decrease the time complexity from O(nk!) to O(n). @AlexHall

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is to use a loop.  Split your message into individual words, and then check for each of those in the sentence *in general*.

```
word_list = message.split()     # this gives you a list of words to find
word_found = True
for word in word_list:
    if word not in message2:
        word_found = False

print(word_found)
```

The flag `word_found` is `True` iff all words were found in the sentence.  There are many ways to make this shorter and faster, especially using the `all` operator, and providing the word list as an in-line expression.

```
word_found = all(word in message2 for word in message.split())
```

Now, if you need to restrict your "found" property to matching exact words, you'll need more preprocessing.  The above code is too forgiving of substrings, such as finding "Are you OK ?" in the sentence "your joke is only barely funny".  For the more restrictive case, you should break `message2` into words, strip those words of punctuation, drop them to lower-case (to make matching easier), and then look for each word (from `message`) in the *list* of words from `message2`.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that what you really need  but this worked you can tested

```
message= 'hello world'
message2= ' hello beautiful world' 
if 'hello' in message and 'world'  in message :
  print('yes')
else :
  print('no')
if   'hello' in message2 and 'world'  in message2 :
  print('yes')
```

out put :
yes 
yes

Comment: Words must be consistently mooted. On the option " hello beautiful world "the result should be"No".